# VBA Variant Index out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I need to expand an existing Worksheet and keep its formatting. There are 7 sections with variable length (in rows) and a width of 14 columns that need to be completed. So what I am trying to do is the following:

- find the lines where the sections start
- select the data out of each section and save it into an array (i thought about this as an array of length 7 and each entry contains a 2-dim. array with the data in it)
- select my new data and expand the existing array (created in the last step) with that new data
- override the current sheet with my new created array
- add formatting

I managed to do step 1 and am currently struggling at step 2: I need to create an array with variable length where I can insert the data.

My code so far:

```
' this should create the array with the 7 entries
' "myArray" contains the row-numbers where the sections start
Function GenerateSheetArray(sheet As Worksheet, myArray As Variant) As Variant

    Dim finalArray As Variant
    Dim myInt As Integer

    'here each entry should be filled
    For i = 0 To 6
        myInt = myArray(i)
        finalArray(i) = GenerateArrayPart(sheet, myInt)
    Next

    GenerateSheetArray = finalArray

End Function

'This should fill each entry with the data of corresponding section
Function GenerateArrayPart(sheet As Worksheet, headline As Integer) As Variant
    Dim leftIndex As Integer, rightIndex As Integer, rowcount As Integer
    Dim sheetArray() As Variant

    rowcount = 0
    leftIndex = 1
    rightIndex = 14
    i = headline + 1

    Do While sheet.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        rowcount = rowcount + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    If (rowcount > 0) Then
        For colIndex = leftIndex To rightIndex
            For rowIndex = 1 To rowcount
                Row = headline + rowIndex
                sheetArray(rowIndex - 1, colIndex - 1) = sheet.Cells(Row, colIndex)
            Next
        Next
    End If

    GenerateArrayPart = sheetArray
End Function
```

Now my problem is, that VBA throws an error at this line:

```
'atm rowIndex and colIndex are 1, Row is 40
'I know that there is data in that cell
sheetArray(rowIndex - 1, colIndex - 1) = sheet.Cells(Row, colIndex)
```

VBA says:

> Index out of range

in method `GenerateArrayPart`.
How can this happen? I thought that `variant` can be pretty much everything and also does not need bounds to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not having any value in the array. Thus, the array is only declared and not dimensionized.

Try this:

```
Dim finalArray As Variant
Redim finalArray(6)
```

Now, the array would have 7 values inside. From 0 to 6. The same error happens in the `Function GenerateArrayPart`, with the array `sheetArray`. There you need to declare the array as a multidimensional array. E.g. `Redim sheetArray (N, M)`.

To see some small working sample, take a look at the code below:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim finalArr As Variant
    ReDim finalArr(6)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(finalArr) To UBound(finalArr)
        finalArr = GenerateArrPart(i)
    Next i

    For i = LBound(finalArr) To UBound(finalArr)
        Debug.Print i; finalArr(i, i)
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function GenerateArrPart(a As Long) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrReturn As Variant
    ReDim arrReturn(a + 1, a + 1)

    For i = LBound(arrReturn) To UBound(arrReturn)
        arrReturn(i, i) = a * i
    Next i

    GenerateArrPart = arrReturn

End Function
```

This is the output:

```
 0  0 
 1  6 
 2  12 
 3  18 
 4  24 
 5  30 
 6  36 
 7  42
```

Comment: You mean I should use "redim" everytime I add a new value to expand the range? since `Redim sheetArray(N, M)` needs two constants and I need to behave like lists in this case I can not just use it once at the very beginning of that function

Comment: @Rüdiger - every time you are expanding an array, you have to redim, yes. And if you want to keep the old values, use the word `Preserve`. Like `Redim Preserve finalArray(100)`.

Comment: @Rüdiger - if you do not like to `Redim` every time, the `Collection` object is at your disposal.